# Getting disordered frame (see image) when using FFMPEG and OpenCV inside docker

Tags: python, docker, ffmpeg

I am consuming an UDP video streaming (from my windows host), when I use the FFMPEG and OpenCV in windows to get the frames, everything is working as expected (completed frames and right colours).

Once I introduce the solution to a docker container, the frames that I am getting are similar to this one:

[disorder images parts in the frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vR88c.jpg)

Also, as in the video we have data stream and video, we are using this ffmepg command to receive raw video frames in another process:

```
process = sp.Popen(shlex.split('ffmpeg -hide_banner '                        # Set loglevel to quiet for disabling the prints ot stderr
                                   '-i "udp://localhost:13437?pkt_size=1348" '                                        # Input stream
                                   '-map 0:v:0 -c:v rawvideo -pix_fmt bgr24 -f:v rawvideo pipe:2  ' # rawvideo format is mapped to stderr pipe (raw video codec with bgr24 pixel format)
                                   #'-map 0:d -c copy -copy_unknown -f:d data pipe:1 '            # Copy the data without ddecoding.
                                   '-report'),                                                   # Create a log file (because we can't the statuses that are usually printed to stderr).
                                    stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE)
```

I have tested by reducing the packet size but the problem persists.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How does `ffmpeg` or **OpenCV** discover the height and width of your raw frame? I understood they are mandatory for raw data.

Comment: Currently I am hard coding as I know it. If I have this solution working, I guess I can extract the resolution with ffprobe command, and use as an argument in the pipe.  Maybe the problem is related with lost udp packets, so the image I get is the combination of two frames because in raw video it is not possible to know the starting frame pixel?

Comment: not reproducible. please present a [mre]. MRE means, if you don't need opencv for this, then don't.